# How do I change the font weight for a Bootstrap 4 modal header?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How do I increase the font weight in the following Bootstrap 4 modal "header"?

Bonus points: I'd also like to make the font color = "#7f7f7f"...

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!
Sean

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue? and you mean `modal-header` this header ?

Comment: There's no "issue" per se, just a formatting preference. Do you know how to make the title/header of a Bootstrap 4 modal "bolder"?

Comment: Either change the "modal-header", or the "modal-title" to make it bolder. I'm a total CSS/Bootstrap newb so this is probably a pretty simple fix, I'd guess.

Comment: Yeah added the code, kindly verify below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `CSS` selector to either `modal-title` or `modal-header` a properties of `color`, `font-size` and `font-weight` to the header .

```css
.modal-title {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #7f7f7f;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Technicalmirchi is this for me?!